# A question about solution of a system of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Dear mathematics community, I got a question like this:

$A,B$ are two square matrixes of order $n$, and $A=(B-\frac1 {110}E)^T(B+\frac1{110}E)$, prove that for any $n-$dimensional vector $\xi$,  there exists at least one non-zero solution for the system of equations $A^T(A^2+A)X=A^T\xi$.

I don't see any hope in expending $A$, then the $A$ and $A^T$ reminded me of *the least square solution* , i.e., there exists at least one non-zero solution for the system of equations $A^T(A^2+A)X=A^T\xi $ if and only if there exists at least one non-zero least square solution for $(A+I)X=\xi$. So I need to prove that $\xi=0$ is not the least square solution for $(A+I)X=\xi$, then I was stuck.

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: What is this $A^{'}$?

Comment: @Find_X the transpose of $A$